# How do objects deform if we apply pressure at a single point?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain

Suppose, we have a large solid object and we apply a pressure to it a single point (let say, with a finger, or a needle). How does the deformation of the surface depend on the force with which we press? I imagine, the deformation is the largest at the point of pressure and drops further away. Is there some simple law by which it drops?

Comment: This is called the Boussinesq problem—and that should give you a lifetime’s worth of reading in terms of analytical and numerical solutions and practical applications.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know the name of the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Boussinesq problem](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/2ea98fbf-d001-4dff-8a63-d3555f559b5b/1006864.pdf).

The deformation from a downward point load $P$, for example, on an isotropic and uniform elastic half-space (also called a semi-infinite solid) with shear modulus $G$ and Poisson ratio $\nu$ is

$$u_i=\frac{P}{4\pi G}\left[\frac{x_ix_3}{R^3}+(3-4\nu)\frac{\delta_{i3}}{R}-\left(\frac{1-2\nu}{R+x_3}\right)\left(\delta_{i3}+\frac{x_i}{R}\right)\right],$$

where $R=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) that's 1 when the indices match and 0 otherwise. This is derived [here](https://www.ajouronline.com/index.php/AJAS/article/view/5060/2659) and [here](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/EN224/halfspace/halfspace.html), for example.

Note that the solution diverges directly under the load, requiring us to integrate this solution over a finite area if we're interested in locations of small $R$. (I happened to publish on this problem for the case of a [tangential load on a finite elastic layer atop a rigid support](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/Influence%20of%20finite%20thickness%20and%20stiffness.pdf).)